# SETVERIABLE not working in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

i have a senerio where i need to get the previous month data.
 so i created two flows in the mapping flow 1 will get the dates of first and last months and i am using parameter veriables and calling them in  mapping 2  in source sql, but for some reason the sql is not taking the parm vlaues, even after the vlaues are there in it.

```
SETVARIABLE($$END_DATE,set_$$END_DATE_v)   ----------------------
```

this the condition i am using to get the $$END_DATE(  which is set in paramters), so iam getting end date as 20160930
and in the source sql i said:
 `PAL.EXCLS_PAID_DATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE($$START_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')  AND  TO_DATE($$END_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')`,
 but its returing 
`PAL.EXCLS_PAID_DATE BETWEEN  TO_DATE(,'YYYYMMDD')  AND  TO_DATE(,'YYYYMMDD')` and throwing error as missing expression

Comment: Are you using $$START_DATE and $$END_DATE in source sql?

Comment: Yes,  the above logic which is mentioned is used in the source sql

Comment: Its an informatica utility, if you are using this in a source query, it will not work. You just need a column names in the source query. Use the logic of $$START_DATE and $$END_DATE in the ports in the expression transformation

Answer (score 0):

1. SETVARIABLE works. But in a different way.
2. You may try to set $$START_DATE and $$END_DATE values on Workflow level and then use them in Source Qualifier
3. Or do the same within SQL statement used to get the data.